# Stored procedure gives an empty reader

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldatareader

I have the following Stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.USER_AUTH
(
@username varchar,
@password varchar
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE username = @username
AND password = @password;
END
```

And there are Two rows in the users table.

This gives an empty reader error

```
_Command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[USER_AUTH]", _Connection);
_Command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", _Username);
_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", _Password);
reader = _Command.ExecuteReader();
```

While this works fine

```
_Command = new SqlCommand("select * from users where 
                    username=@username and password=@password" , _Connection);
_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", _Username);
_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", _Password);
reader = _Command.ExecuteReader();
```

Where `_Connection` is `SqlConnection _Connection` , `_Command` is `SqlCommand _Command` and
`reader` is `SqlDataReader`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your stored procedure declares

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.USER_AUTH
(
   @username varchar,
   @password varchar
)
```

without specifying a size for the two varchars. In this way just one char is passed to the parameters and of course nothing is retrieved

Change the sp to

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.USER_AUTH
(
   @username nvarchar(30),
   @password nvarchar(30)
)
```

or whatever size are your two database fields

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the length for `varchar` 
So if we don't specify the length ourself these are the default values SQL Server uses - which means the data what we would be expecting to get stored in the database would have got silently truncated without our knowledge.

[Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.USER_AUTH
(
@username varchar(20),
@password varchar(20)
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE username = @username
AND password = @password;
END
```